# How to become a Jenkins user?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have installed Jenkins and during installation an user named `jenkins` has been created. I can see from the documentation:

[The 'jenkins' user is created to run this service.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu)

Now I need to become this `jenkins` user. I have in the following ways:

```
[root@hostname ~]# sudo su - jenkins
[root@hostname ~]# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

[root@hostname tmp]# su - jenkins
[root@hostname tmp]# whoami
root
```

Why switch user to the jenkins user is not working?

I am on RHEL.

```
cat /etc/*release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
```

Comment: What's the command you used to create the user?

Comment: I have installed Jenkins and during installation an user named jenkins has been created. I dont even know how that user is created.

Comment: My guess would be that the user is locked. Do `passwd -u jenkins` and then try again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically for this Jenkins user `jenkins` bash was not configured.

```
jenkins:x:496:492:Jenkins Continuous Build server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/false
```

So we need to set the bash for this user and that resolved the issue. I used the following command:

```
sudo usermod -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

See below:

```
jenkins:x:496:492:Jenkins Continuous Build server:/var/lib/jenkins:/bin/bash
```

And now I can perform su and can use bash.

Answer (score 11):

It's more like a queastion for [superuser](https://superuser.com/) but:

You don't need `sudo` when switching the user. `su` will ask for the users password anyway:

```
su - jenkins
```

You can also use `sudo` to execute a single command as another user with the `-u` option. If that command is a shell, you'll get a shell. E.g.:

```
sudo -u jenkins /bin/bash
```

Comment: `sudo -u jenkins /bin/bash` worked without password prompt

Answer (score 10):

It is also possible to run:

```
su - jenkins -s /bin/bash
```